# Advice with method please

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Posting again as was closed before I had time to answer!

I have been thinking about this over and over!.... I thought I had cracked it but it seems not. So I am making a simple booking system and needed to prevent double bookings.

So I create a document using variables like Date TicketType Place Plot I combine these and insert into firebase. So on a given date and plot, a person can book a ticket of type ,Day Night, 24hour. I have made it so the code checks for the document created I mentioned above. This works great as you cant book any ticket of the same type. So my problem is that if a user picks a day or night ticket I can still go ahead and book 24hr ticket on same day . Can anybody please help me with some logic or sample code how to prevent this happening please.

with some code

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:swimfinder/Models/swimlakes.dart';
import 'package:swimfinder/common_widgets/provider_widget.dart';

class Booking extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Booking createState() => _Booking();
  final String name;
  const Booking({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);
}

class _Booking extends State<Booking> {
  SwimLake lake = SwimLake();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCurrentUser();
    getLakeData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _loadCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() {
        this.currentUser = user;
      });
    });
  }

  getLakeData() async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('swimfinderlakes')
        .document(widget.name)
        .get()
        .then((result) {
      //lake.active = result.data['active'];
      lake.address = result.data['address'];
      //lake.advert = result.data['advert'];
      lake.description = result.data['description'];
      lake.email = result.data['email'];
      lake.id = result.data['id'];;
      lake.name = result.data['name'];
      lake.swimplots = result.data['swimplots'];
      lake.telephone = result.data['telephone'];
      lake.website = result.data['website'];
    });
  }

  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  var data;
  bool autoValidate = true;
  bool readOnly = false;
  bool showSegmentedControl = true;
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  List<String> plots = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return lakebookingage(context, snapshot);
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget lakebookingage(context, snapshot) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getLakeData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            plots = lake.swimplots.split(',');
            return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text(
                        lake.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      leading: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_backspace,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                    ),
                    body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(lake.mainimage),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: BackdropFilter(
                            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1, sigmaY: 1),
                            child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: FormBuilder(
                          key: _fbKey,
                          initialValue: {
                            'bookedondata': DateTime.now(),
                            'emailaddr': currentUser.email,
                            'lake': lake.name,
                            'mainimage': lake.mainimage,
                            'dismissed': false,
                            'reviewed': false,
                            'uid': currentUser.uid,

                            //'accept_terms': false,
                          },
                          autovalidate: true,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(height: 20),
                                FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
                                  attribute: "bookedfordate",
                                  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  resetIcon: null,
                                  inputType: InputType.date,
                                  validators: [
                                    FormBuilderValidators.required()
                                  ],
                                  format: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Reservation Date",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(height: 20),
                                FormBuilderDropdown(
                                  attribute: "tickettype",
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Ticket Type",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // initialValue: 'Male',
                                  hint: Text('Day/Night/24Hour'),
                                  validators: [
                                    FormBuilderValidators.required()
                                  ],
                                  items: ['Day', 'Night', '24Hour']
                                      .map((ticket) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                          value: ticket,
                                          child: Text("$ticket")))
                                      .toList(),
                                ),
                                Container(height: 20),
                                FormBuilderDropdown(
                                  attribute: "swimplot",
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Select Swim",
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // initialValue: 'Male',
                                  hint:
                                      Text('Which pitch do you wish to choose'),
                                  validators: [
                                    FormBuilderValidators.required()
                                  ],
                                  items: plots
                                      .map((ticket) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                          value: ticket,
                                          child: Text("$ticket")))
                                      .toList(),
                                ),
                                Container(height: 20),
                                RaisedButton.icon(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.search,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Book",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      )),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _bookswim();
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(10.0))),
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ])));
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }





  

  void getDocument() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('bookings')
        .where("bookedfordate", isEqualTo: DateTime.now())
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments()
        .then(
      (value) {
        if (value.documents.length > 0) {
          //return _myClassFromSnapshot(value.documents[0]);
        } else {
          //return _bookswim
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void _bookswim() {
    //getDocument();
    _fbKey.currentState.save();
    if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String combine = ((DateFormat('yyyyMMdd')
              .format(_fbKey.currentState.value['bookedfordate'])) +
          (_fbKey.currentState.value['swimplot']) +
          (_fbKey.currentState.value['tickettype']) +
          (widget.name.replaceAll(RegExp(' '), '')));

      Firestore.instance
          .collection("bookings")
          .document(combine)
          .get()
          .then((doc) {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          Firestore.instance.collection('bookings').document(combine).setData({
            'bookedfordate': _fbKey.currentState.value['bookedfordate'],
            'emailaddr': _fbKey.currentState.value['emailaddr'],
            'lake': _fbKey.currentState.value['lake'],
            'mainimage': _fbKey.currentState.value['mainimage'],
            'dismissed': _fbKey.currentState.value['dismissed'],
            'reviewed': _fbKey.currentState.value['reviewed'],
            'uid': _fbKey.currentState.value['uid'],
            'bookedondata': _fbKey.currentState.value['bookedondata'],
            'tickettype': _fbKey.currentState.value['tickettype'],
            'swimplot': _fbKey.currentState.value['swimplot']
          });
          _showDialog();
        } else {
          _showMyDialog();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('SwimFinder'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Sorry this Swim in already booked!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("SwimFinder",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
                fontSize: 20,
              )),
          content: new Text("Thank you for your booking!",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
                fontSize: 20,
              )),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So if a user selects 24hr ticket it is for 1 day at a certain swim and a certain plot. After this Day and Night tickets should tell the user not available. A day ticket and night ticket can be booked on the same day as this is 24hr but could be for 2 different user's.

I hope from my code it makes a little more sense

Comment: Please don't reask a closed question. Make edits to your existing closed question. If your edits fix the original issues, it will be reopened.

Comment: its not the code which is not making sense, your words, I am plainly unable to understand the idea

Comment: Ok, So imagine having a hotel with 5 rooms. The rooms are only available to book for daytime, nighttime or 24hrs. From my code you can see if I book day I cant book day again and same for night and 24hrs. But if a user books day or night first it is still possible to book 24hrs... I hope that makes sense

Comment: @neuromancer did you have any advice ?

Comment: given 24 hrs in a day, define what time of the day you consider day and night

Comment: Day 0700 - 1900
Night = 1900 - 0700
24hrs 0700 - 0700

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your response to my questions on Google Groups Flutter ie:

> I am not clear on what constitutes a double booking ie. what you are trying to prevent. Please confirm or correct each of the following:

1. Your equivalent of a 'room' is a 'swim plot'? YES!
2. A 'swim plot' can be booked for 'day', 'night' or '24 hrs' on any given date?  YES!
3. These 'time slots' can only be booked by one user on any given day ie. there is no sharing of a time slot by two or more users? CORRECT!
4. If booked for '24 hrs' then a 'swim plot' is not available for either 'day' or 'night' booking? CORRECT!
5. If booked for 'day' then a 'swim plot' is still available for 'night' but not for '24 hrs', and similar if booked for 'night'? CORRECT!
6. User B can book 'day' if User A has booked 'night' on the same date? CORRECT!

I use Firebase RTDB rather than Firestore so you will need to 'translate' the following into a Firestore document structure - you question was about logic, which hopefully my answer addresses so that should be ok.

I would create a 'booking' node / record on the database with a compound key of `'swim plot id' + 'date'`. The record would simply contain three properties, one for each of the possible time slots ie.

```
'24hrs': 'userid of person booking it'
'day': 'userid of person booking it' 
'night': 'userid of person booking it'
```

The other data such as user email, images, etc. should not be on the booking record, imho, but should be read from other nodes/documents using the userid, swim plot id, etc. as necessary.

When a booking is attempted the logic is as follows:

You read the db looking for `swimPlotId + date`

If record doesn't exist then create one with the user's id filled in against the appropriate time slot property. The other two will remain blank/null. Tell the user booking is made.

If the record exists then

If the 24hrs property exists/has userid (and it is not his userid) - tell user that no booking can be made.

If he wants to book 24hrs and either day or night exists/has userid (and it is not his userid) - tell user that no booking can be made.

If he wants to book day and it doesn't exist/have userid - update the record with a day property of value his userid - tell user that a booking is made.

If he wants to book night and it doesn't exist/have userid - update the record with a night property of value his userid  - tell user that a booking is made.

I think that covers it.

ps. Given your 24hrs is not all on one date, you will need to create some artificial 'date' for your key that ensures it is correctly identified, or you can use the date of the day in which 7am falls and control the 'overlap' in any code that refers to 'date' - probably write a little method that controls the overlap in one place and just call the method whenever referring to date.